# Where is __builtin_va_start defined?

Tags: gcc, glibc

I'm trying to locate where `__builtin_va_start` is defined in GCC's source code, and see how it is implemented. (I was looking for where `va_start` is defined and then found that this macro is defined as `__builtin_va_start`.) I used `cscope -r` in GCC 9.1's source code directory to search the definition but haven't found it. Can anyone point where this function is defined?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewvc/gcc/trunk/gcc/builtins.c?view=markup#l5162

Comment: But **why do you ask?** You just use [`<stdarg.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/va_arg.3.html) and you should *not* care about implementation details. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56412342/edit) your question to add several paragraphs of motivation

Comment: Without some motivation, the question is unclear and too broad. I am voting to close it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please see the comment above that answered your question.

Comment: You should have explained that in your question, *not* in a comment. As a rule of thumb, *never* comment your own question (instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56412342/edit) your question to improve it). I still feel it should be closed, precisely because you have *not edited* your question

Comment: I gave the exact same information as [cpplearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner) in my answer, by mentioning *in my answer* the `expand_builtin_va_start` function of `builtins.c`. A simple `grep` would have found the line refered by cpplearner

Comment: BTW, how to cite your paper in BibTeX format? That should go in your question too...

Comment: Precisely with your lacking motivation I could have given a more focused answer. And that reason alone would have made me downvote twice, if I could. A question should be selfcontained, even with all its comments removed

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not a co-author of that paper. You can find the bibtex from ACM digital library or from USENIX's website for this paper if you Google. I'm glad  people are interested in this topic, but I don't think I should put the information of the paper in the original question. Again, I think my question is clear enough and the motivation is obvious (and self-contained): the questioner would like to know the implementation of that macro. Some people may be interested in knowing why I want to know the implementation, but that's just remotely relevant to the question itself, IMHO.

Comment: We disagree. Lack of motivation in your question makes it barely understandable, and certainly off-topic on StackOverflow. And the very title of your question is, as I answered, wrong and shows a lot of misunderstanding

Answer (score 7):

**That `__builtin_va_start` is *not defined* anywhere**. It is a [GCC compiler builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (a bit like `sizeof` is a compile-time operator). It is an *implementation detail* related to the [`<stdarg.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/va_arg.3.html) [standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) (provided by the compiler, not the C standard library implementation `libc`). What really matters are the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) followed by the generated assembler.

GCC has special code to deal with compiler builtins. And that code is not *defining* the builtin, but *implementing* its ad-hoc *behavior* inside the compiler. And `__builtin_va_start` is *expanded* into some compiler-specific *internal representation* of your compiled C/C++ code, specific to GCC (some [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html#GIMPLE) perhaps)

<sup>From a comment of yours, I would infer that you are interested in implementation details. But **that should be in your question**</sup>

If you study GCC 9.1 source code, look inside *some* of **`gcc-9.1.0/gcc/builtins.c`** (the `expand_builtin_va_start` function there), and for *other* builtins inside `gcc-9.1.0/gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.c`, `gcc-9.1.0/gcc/cppbuiltin.c`, `gcc-9.1.0/gcc/jit/jit-builtins.c`

You could write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (in 2Q2019, for GCC 9, and the C++ code of your plugin might have to change for the future GCC 10) to add your own GCC builtins. BTW, you might even *overload* the behavior of the *existing* `__builtin_va_start` by your own specific code, and/or you might have -at least for research purposes- your own `stdarg.h` header with `#define va_start(v,l)   __my_builtin_va_start(v,l)` and have your GCC plugin understand your `__my_builtin_va_start` plugin-specific builtin. Be however aware of the [GCC runtime library exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html) and read its rationale: I am not a lawyer, but I tend to believe that you should (and that legal document requires you to) publish your GCC plugin with some open source license.

You first need to **read a textbook on compilers, such as the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)**, to understand that an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is mostly *transforming* internal representations of your compiled code.

You further need to spend months in studying the many internal representations of GCC. Remember, **[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is a *very complex* program** (of about ten millions lines of code). Don't expect to understand it with only a few days of work. Look inside the [GCC resource center website](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/).

My dead [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project had references and [slides](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) explaining more of GCC (the design philosophy and architecture of GCC changes slowly; so the concepts are still relevant, even if individual details changed). **It took me almost *ten years* full time to partly understand some of the middle-end layers of GCC**. I cannot transmit that knowledge in a StackOverflow answer.

My [*draft* Bismon report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) (work in progress, funded by H2020, so lot of bureaucracy) has a dozen of pages (in its sections §1.3 and 1.4) introducing the internal representations of GCC.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding "a GCC builtin is not defined anywhere". Can you elaborate a bit on this? To my understanding, during the compilation, at some point, `__builtin_va_start` would be replaced by some code. I'm trying to understand what code is it replaced and where that code is defined.

Comment: Yes. your understanding is wrong. You need to spend months in reading more about compiler implementation and GCC internals.

Comment: Could you please tell me how the compiler "understands" what those builtin functions do if they are not "defined" somewhere?

Comment: I am sorry, I gave several references but you need years of work