# Two functions share same signature in C

Tags: c, function, file, overloading

I read that C doesn't suppose function overloading. But in this Slide we can see it's not correct and my professor said: "How Is it possible that we have 2 different signatures for same function name in C?"

[image]

Can someone explain this?

Comment: The `open` function in this respect is more like `printf`: a single function that accepts a variable number of arguments.  For `printf`, the number of `%`-specifiers in the format string tells `printf` how many more arguments to expect.  For `open`, the presence of the `O_CREAT` bit in `flags` tells it whether to expect the third `mode` argument.

Comment: From [Optional arguments in C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27795855): _"If you look today at recent implementation of that open function in free software libc implementations on Linux, such as [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/), you see in its [src/fcntl/open.c](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/fcntl/open.c) that it uses the [<stdarg.h> variadic facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) (which are [often implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56412342/841108) as compiler builtins."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible. Code such as this:

```
int open(const char* path, int flags);
int open(const char* path, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

is invalid C and will not compile (but valid C++).

However, C supports *variadic functions* and the old `open` function is implemented using that. It's actually declared as:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```

Where the `...` allows a variable amount of arguments through the features of `stdarg.h`.

Comment: Notably, variadic functions are very unsafe because of their non-existent type safety and indeterministic behavior. Such functions are to be regarded as obsolete and to be avoided in production-quality code. We only need to look at `stdio.h` to see why -  this library is perhaps the single-most harmful library every written in any programming language, using the cost of all damage caused to mankind as metric. So please don't run off to implement your own variadic functions in new projects - _very bad idea_.

Comment: Agreed. The only time I'm using them is to write wrappers around existing library functions.

Comment: @Lundin I 100% agree with you about the unsafety of variadic functions (especially from `<stdio.h>`), but one must acknowledge that unfortunately the C language never added proper meta-programming/generics features that would allow a 100% type-safe version of, e.g., `printf()` to be written (yes, you can with a mix of rudimentary preprocessor macros and `_Generic`, but it's far from safe and extensible). It's such a PITA, IMHO.

Comment: @LucaPolito Yep. The lack of overloading is one of the biggest flaws in C IMO

Comment: @LucaPolito Not necessarily. Indeterminate function interfaces often originate from muddy program design. The correct way to design such an API might be to pass an object instead (struct in C).

Comment: @Lundin I get your point (don't get me started with the [25-parameter monstrous functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)!!), but I was thinking about something like `println!()` macro in Rust (safe, easy to use, and very powerful). @klutt Not necessarily function overloading, but just simple generic templates would reduce the amount of boilerplate in C *by a lot*.

Comment: @LucaPolito Or look at the equivalent file handling API in Java, where you pass a SpecializedFunctionThingie to a LessSpecializedFunctionThingie to a GenericFunctionThingie, preferably in one 500 characters long one-liner using anonymous class objects :) It's definitely not just stdio.h which got a big fail API. As for C, someone could just write a type safe debug/log printing library, using macros with _Generic. It only becomes cumbersome if you have to implement those macros over and over for every single project.