# A way to pass an optional argument to a function

Tags: c

Take the following function:

```
char * slice(const char * str, unsigned int start, unsigned int end) {

    int string_len = strlen(str);
    int slice_len = (end - start < string_len) ? end - start : string_len;
    char * sliced_str = (char *) malloc (slice_len + 1);
    sliced_str[slice_len] = '\0';

    // Make sure we have a string of length > 0, and it's within the string range
    if (slice_len == 0 || start >= string_len || end <= 0) return "";

    for (int i=0, j=start; i < slice_len; i++, j++)
        sliced_str[i] = str[j];

    return sliced_str;

}
```

I can call this as follows:

```
char * new_string = slice("old string", 3, 5)
```

Is there a way to be able to "omit" an argument somehow in C? For example, passing something like the following:

```
char * new_string = slice("old string", 3, NULL)
// NULL means ignore the  `end` parameter and just go all the way to the end.
```

How would something like that be done? Or is that not possible to do in C?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795767/optional-arguments-in-c-function) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional arguments in C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795767/optional-arguments-in-c-function)

Comment: Not possible in C. But in your case its easily solvable by using an if statement since char* are zero terminated

Comment: BTW, the POSIX standard already has the function you are implementing yourself: `char *slice(const char *str, size_t start, size_t end) { return strndup(str + start, end - start); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only two ways to pass optional arguments in C, and only one is common. Either pass a pointer to the optional argument and understand NULL as not passed, or pass an out-of-range value as not passed.

Way 1:

```
char * slice(const char * str, const unsigned int *start, const unsigned int *end);

// ...
const unsigned int three = 3;
char * new_string = slice("old string", &three, NULL)
```

Way 2:

```
#include <limits.h>

char * slice(const char * str, const unsigned int start, const unsigned int end);


char * new_string = slice("old string", 3, UINT_MAX);
```

BTW, this example should really be using `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` but I copied your prototype.

The proposed dupe target is talking about vardiac functions, which do have optional arguments, but it's not like what you're asking for. It's always possible in such a function call to determine if the argument is (intended to be) present by looking at the arguments that come before. In this case, that won't help at all.

Comment: Which is the common way?

Comment: @Shared: First one.

Answer (score 1):

Optional arguments (or arguments that have default values) are not really a thing in C. I think you have the right idea by passing in 'NULL', except for that NULL is equal to 0 and will be interpreted as an integer. Instead, I would recommend changing the argument to a signed integer instead of unsigned, and passing in a -1 as your flag to indicate that the argument should be ignored.